# python matrix multiplication: how to handle very large matrices?

Tags: python, numpy, matrix-multiplication

```
a = numpy.zeros((17770,5))

b = numpy.zeros((5,20000))

ma = numpy.matrix(a)

mb = numpy.matrix(b)
```

That is, `ma.shape = (17770,5)`, `mb.shape = (5,20000)`, both are `numpy.matrix`.

I need `ma*mb`. But I get the error message `"ValueError: array is too big"`.

Are these matrices too large for Python multiplication?

BTW, I tested with python2.6.6/32bit/3GB RAM

Comment: Consider memory mapping, if you really need to have a product matrix that is so big.

Answer (score 5):

I can compute `ma*mb` on my machine (`Python 2.7.1 |EPD 7.0-2 (64-bit)` on 64-bit Ubuntu).

Make sure you're using 64-bit Python on a 64-bit OS since a 17770x20000 matrix of double-precision floats requires 2.8GB of RAM, which exceeds (or is very close to) what most 32-bit platforms can handle.

Depending on your requirements, using single-precision floats (`numpy.float32`) might also be a possibility.

Lastly, if your matrices are sparse or have structure you might want to look into exploiting that to reduce memory requirements.

Comment: You mean I run out of the memory?